# Play sound from array on Android

Tags: android, audio

Solved: I forgot the track.play(); at the end...

I want to play a sound on my Android Smartphone (4.0.4 Api level 15).
I tried to hear some random noise, but its not working:

```
public class Sound {

  private static int length = 22050 * 10; //10 seconds long
  private static byte[] data = new byte[length];

  static void fillRandom() {
    new Random().nextBytes(data); //Create some random noise to listen to.
  }

  static void play() {

    fillRandom();

    final int TEST_SR = 22050; //This is from an example I found online.
    final int TEST_CONF = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    final int TEST_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    final int TEST_MODE = AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC; //I need static mode.
    final int TEST_STREAM_TYPE = AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM;
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(TEST_STREAM_TYPE, TEST_SR, TEST_CONF, TEST_FORMAT, length, TEST_MODE);
    track.write(data, 0, length);
  }
}
```

I have played a little bit with the variabels, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have left to do is play it. Add this line to the end of your play() function:

```
track.play();
```