# How create a file audio using a byte array in android studio?

Tags: java, file, android-studio, audio, byte

I have a function that receives a byte array and saves it in "file.mp3", the "file.mp3" is saved in the cell phone but can not be opened.

I used MediaPlayer following this post [Android - Playing mp3 from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972027/android-playing-mp3-from-byte) but it kills the application by doing it in this way, instead of temporarily creating the file, i directly save it in the phone, but the "file.mp3" does not work.

Following this other post [Play sound from array on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033942/play-sound-from-array-on-android) i test that it works if it takes a random array of bytes, but when i use my array of bytes, it also does not work.

I have this function:

```
@GET("tts/talk/{text}")
Call<ResponseBody> sendText(@Path("text") String text);
```

I send a text to my REST API and i get an array of bytes through `ResponseBody` following this way:

```
    public void sendText(String text){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = ttsService.sendText(text);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){                       
                    try {
                        downloadMp3(response.body().bytes());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                }
            }
    }
```

The function `downloadMp3(response.body ().bytes())`, it receives an array of bytes and saves it in file.mp3 directly on the phone:

```
    private void downloadMp3(byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) {
        try {

            File file = new File(    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "audio.mp3"
                );
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is this way of saving the array of bytes okay? 
Is there another way to save an array of bytes in an file.mp3 or any audio file or must there be a processing of that array of bytes before?

Comment: Try to encode to 64 base following the link Bellow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448865/base64-encode-audio-file-and-send-as-a-string-then-decode-the-string